# SharePoint modern quick launch not showing until refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, quick-launch

When I open a subsite in SharePoint modern experience, the quick launch on the side does not show.

As soon as I refresh the page, it shows. I have tried multiple things, all of which are not working.

Comment: Are you using Modern sites in SharePoint online, or SharePoint 2019 Server on-premises?  Is this a team site or a Communication Site?  Do you have any SPFx application customizers installed?

Comment: Modern SharePoint online. Team site. And no.

Comment: You mention that you have "tried multiple things", can you summarize what you have tried?

Comment: which template did you use for creating the sub?

Comment: Did you at one point have the quick-launch disabled on this subsite, but then re-enable it?

Comment: I tried disabling the quick-launch then re-enable it. I tried creating the sub sites with different options checked(just in case, never know). Same across all browsers. But I have another share point, set up the same way, and it works just fine. I've gone through the settings on both and everything matches up. What I do notice is that if I inspect the page, the one missing the quick-launch is missing the <div class="spNav_f7fd2212"> and obviously the other sharepoints subsite has that. I am not sure why that would not be on the other sharepoint site if everything was done the same

Comment: When i refresh the page, that div shows up, but only after refreshing the page or navigating from one subsite to another. It wont load correctly if coming from the root/home

Comment: I can confirm that there seems to be a caching issue.  If I create a subsite, and then disable the quick launch, I experience the opposite problem, the page initially loads with it visible and only disappears upon refresh.  I opened an incognito window, and it is correctly disabled in that session without needing to refresh.  I then re-enable the quick launch and experience the identical symptoms you report, until I close and start a new incognito session, then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Go to the top level site's Site Settings page as an admin

2.Click **Navigation Elements** >> Tick the "**Enable Quick Launch**" checkbox

[image]

[image]

3.Go to the subsite's Site Settings page as an admin

4.Click **Navigation**

[image]

5.On the Navigation Settings page, under the "**Global Navigation**" section, please select "**Display the same navigation items as the parent site**" option

[image]

6.Go back the subsite's Site Settings page, click "**Navigation Elements**" link

7.Please tick the "**Enable Quick Launch**" checkbox

[image]